# Spring Boot 3, groovy, docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, groovy, executable-jar

I have a Spring Boot 3 Application with following build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'myPackage'
version = '0.0.1'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz'
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    // für getter und setter als anotation ....
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    // Mysql
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.49'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.groovy/groovy-json
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-json:4.0.14'

}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.named('jar') {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "mypackage.MyProject"
    }
}
```

if I create a jar and use this jar in a docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:17
COPY build/libs/MyProject-*-plain.jar MyProject.jar
EXPOSE 8083
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "MyProject.jar"]
```

I got the error message:

Error: Could not find or load main class mypackage.MyProject
2023-08-28T17:50:37.927951378Z Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject

Thank you for your help ...

Comment: You're running `bootJar` yeah?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong artefact.

`COPY build/libs/MyProject-*-plain.jar MyProject.jar` (note the `-plain` in
the name) is **only your code** in compiled form.  All dependencies are missing.

Check your `build/libs` for the sizes:

```
# ls -lh build/libs/*.jar     
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group  50M Aug 29 07:41 build/libs/project.jar 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 326K Aug 29 07:41 build/libs/project-plain.jar
```

Note the other, larger jar there.  This is the "uber" or "fat" jar
Spring-Boot builds for you, which contains your code but also all your
deps.

When using this jar, you can also remove your own handling for the
`main-class` in the manifest; the plugin already does that for the fat
jar.

If you have problems with picking this file for the `COPY`, you can tell
the Spring-Boot plugin to use a different name like this:

```
bootJar.archiveClassifier = "fat"
```

This will result in a file ending with `-fat.jar`.

Note beside: `openjdk` always was a **non-production** image and now is even
deprecated.